# Dogecoin: No wallet has been loaded

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, wallet.dat, dogecoin

I downloaded many [X] core software, including Bitcoin, Litecoin and others, and they all worked fine, except for Dogecoin Core. It keeps saying "No wallet has been loaded". There was a `wallet.dat` file there, but I got the same error when it was there (it's an empty wallet, btw). Now I moved that file somewhere else, and Dogecoin core is not creating a new wallet, and keeps giving the same error. How can I fix this? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know the reason now... the problem is that on the official [dogecoin website](http://dogecoin.com/), the version to download is 1.1.0, which is the one I downloaded, but is not the latest. The latest now is 1.8.0 (apparently, according to github). I switched to the new version and the problem was solved.

If the devs of the Dogecoin website are here, please upgrade it.